# how to get li width + margin using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

my code is something like this

```
//css
li{display:inline-block}

//html #li margin and width are dynamic
<ul>
<li style='margin:30px;width:100px;'>Pic</li>
<li style='margin:40px;width:200px;'>Pic</li>
<li style='margin:10px;width:500px;'>Pic</li>
<li style='margin:50px;width:300px;'>Pic</li>
</ul>
```

how to make a jquery function that will take an li index as an input and it will return the width of all li from the beginning to that index + margins ' left + right '

```
Examples // something like this   
myFunction(1); //output 440 (( 30 margin-left [0] + 30 margin-right [0] + 40 margin-left [1] + 40 margin-right [1] + 100 width [0] + 200 width [1] )) 

myFunction(2); //output 960 (( 30 margin-left [0] + 30 margin-right [0] + 40 margin-left [1] + 40 margin-right [1] + 10 margin-left [2] + 10 margin-right [2] + 100 width [0] + 200 width [1] + 500 width [2] ))
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You're looking for `outerWidth(true)`

for example

`$('li:eq(0)').outerWidth(true)`

if you dont want the margin, but only want the padding and border, just do `outerWidth()`

So you can just add up the li's outerWidth's normally to get the sum of them all.

Comment: this output the outWidth for 1 element, but i want my function to output the sum from the first element to that element, you got what i mean  ?

Thanks A lot for helping

Comment: @From.ME.to.YOU: Alex Sexton has shown you the door but you need to open it yourself.

Answer (score 3):

```
$.fn.sumOuterWidth = function(useMargins) {
  var sum = 0;
  this.each(function() { 
    sum += $(this).outerWidth(useMargins);
  });
  return sum;
};

// example sum the width of the first 2 li's:
$('ul li').slice(0,2).sumOuterWidth(true) 

// Also gets the sum of the width of the first 2 li's:
$('ul li:eq(1)').prevAll().andSelf().sumOuterWidth(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//adapt selectors to get only the ul you want
function calculate(i)  {
  if(i >= $("ul").size()) {
    alert("This index doesn't exist");
    return;
  }
  var sum = 0;
  for(var j=0; j<=i; j++) {
    sum = sum + $("ul li:eq("+j+")").outerWidth(true);
  }
  alert("li's width for index "+i+" is "+sum)
}
```